# What does j+= (i=j) mean in C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, operands

I have virtually no experience in programming C. But now i have to use a bit of C code in a VB.net application.

Translating the code has been succesful so far, but i have encountered this weird (at least for me) statement

```
j += ( i = j);
```

both j and i are integers. I have been looking on this forum and Google but found no answer about what it might mean.

A bit further in the C code I have some similar code that looks like

```
chisq += (temp = y[i] - (aa + bb*x[i]), temp*temp);
```

all variables except for i are double or an array of doubles.

Please excuse me if I made some grammar or spelling mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

edit: thanks for all the answers...they are very clear... unfortunatly i've run into a dead-end in my transformation from C to VB.net...

```
struct profile *p = profiles;
double uf[ARRAY_SIZE];
int i;
double u, v, s;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++, p++) {
    if (p->drctn)
        v = phi;
    else    v = TWOPI - phi;
    u = p->xfall*TWOPI;
    uf[i] = -(a0*cos(u + v) - a1*sin(u + v));
}
```

I believe this can't be translated... thanks anyway for all your great information!!!

Comment: This expression is very close to invoking undefined behavior. Don't write crap code like this, instead split the expression in several.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chisq += (temp = y[i] - (aa + bb*x[i]), temp*temp);` will be evaluated in the following way:

`operator ,` of `temp = y[i] - (aa + bb*x[i])` and `temp*temp`
If it is not overloaded than it will evaluate first argument, discard it and then evaluate second argument and return it

```
temp = y[i] - (aa + bb*x[i]);
chisq = chisq + temp*temp;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
j += ( i = j);
```

it's just a ugly way to say

```
i = j;
j = j * 2;
```

Which you can also write as:

```
i = j;
j *= 2;
```

In the same way the second operation will be evaluated in the following order:

```
temp = y[i] - (aa + bb * x[i]);
chisq = chisq + (temp * temp);
```

Comment: Not exactly, you skipped the part about saving j to i

Comment: oh... right... what a ugly code... i will fix my answer immediately! thanks

Answer (score 1):

It firsts assigns j to i, and then adds i to j.

Like this:

```
i = j;
j += i;
```

Comment: @Ben, yes (and assigning i) could be one like:
i = j; j *= 2;

Comment: @Ben: double `j`, but also leave a copy of original value in `i`, and then also a piece of art of coding so that the expression looks like series of strokes.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = j;
j += i;
```

Which is equal to:

```
i = j;
j *= 2; // j += i is the same as j += j which is j = j + j;
```

Finally: It looks like "trick" but in fact is bad practice because of bad readability of program.